# Adding a row with fewer columns to a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

Let's say I have a 10x10 data frame, and I want to add a row to the beginning with just one value (i.e., the new row only has one column). In addition, I want this row to go above the column names, so I would need to turn the column names into actual entries in the data frame. How would I do this without adding NAs?

Here is an example of what I have (a data frame with nrow=3, column headers, and ncol=5):

```
Name Description Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
2345 gene        1.123   1.532   2.464
3253 gene        2.313   1.531   1.424
2453 gene        1.164   1.597   1.943
```

And this is what I want (a data frame/some sort of object with nrow=5 and ncol=5, but NULL values in the first row):

```
#1.2
Name Description Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
2345 gene        1.123   1.532   2.464
3253 gene        2.313   1.531   1.424
2453 gene        1.164   1.597   1.943
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you have multiple "data.frame"s that you want to call at will? Perhaps, it might be better to put them in a "list" and give appropriate "names" to each element.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Is this for display purposes or something functional?

Comment: Ananda - I will be feeding the output into analytical software. I can easily just add the values I need if I open up what I currently have in Excel, but I will have a ton of tables like this that will need to be analyzed, so if I can get a script to do this, that would be ideal.

Comment: So you just need to write in this form to disk. You don't actually *need* it in a data.frame? Because what you've described is simply not "legal" in a data.frame. You can write out a data.frame (which column names and such) with `write.table()` then you can `cat` your "#1.2" value to the same file with `append=T`, and then write the next data.frame to the same file, again with `append=T`.

Comment: I would go with @MrFlick's suggestion. You could probably even collect them in a `list`, create a custom `print` function, and use `capture.output` or `sink` with your new `print` function.

Comment: Thanks all! I'm still an R novice (obviously). Appending works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on my comment, I would try something like the following as a possible approach:

First, some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 5))
B <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 5))
C <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 5))
```

First, as suggested, put the `data.frame`s in a `list`. Set the names of the `list` elements to be what you want printed above the `data.frame`. Here, I've just used the same names as the original `data.frame`s:

```
myList <- list(A = A, B = B, C = C)
```

Second, create a custom `print` function that has a `cat` line and `print.data.frame` with whatever additional settings you need (like `row.names = FALSE`).

```
print.myList <- function(x, ...) {
  invisible(lapply(names(x), function(y) {
    cat("#:", y, "\n")
    print.data.frame(x[[y]], row.names = FALSE)
    cat("\n")
  }))
}
```

For demonstration purposes, I'll write to a `tempfile()`, but you would actually be writing this to a text file somewhere on your computer.

```
temp <- tempfile()
```

The actual "writing" is done by `capture.output`:

```
capture.output(print.myList(myList), file = temp)
```

Here's what our "temp" file looks like now:

```
readLines(temp)
#  [1] "#: A "                                                   
#  [2] "         X1         X2         X3        X4         X5"  
#  [3] " -0.6264538 -0.8356286  0.3295078 0.4874291  0.5757814"  
#  [4] "  0.1836433  1.5952808 -0.8204684 0.7383247 -0.3053884" 
#  [5] ""                                                        
#  [6] "#: B "                                                   
#  [7] "        X1         X2          X3          X4        X5" 
#  [8] " 1.5117812 -0.6212406  1.12493092 -0.01619026 0.8212212" 
#  [9] " 0.3898432 -2.2146999 -0.04493361  0.94383621 0.5939013" 
# [10] ""                                                        
# [11] "#: C "                                                   
# [12] "        X1          X2          X3         X4         X5"
# [13] " 0.9189774  0.07456498  0.61982575 -0.1557955 -0.4781501"
# [14] " 0.7821363 -1.98935170 -0.05612874 -1.4707524  0.4179416"
```

Note: *Of course, if you opened the resulting file in a text editor, you would not see the `[1]` numbers shown here.*